# spark machine learning -- better design

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning

I am trying to implement a machine learning algorithm in Spark. The basic idea is to split the data into N partitions and learn N individual models on each individual dataset partition separately. During prediction we poll these N models and get their o/p and combine them.

a) to partition data into N portions we use `repartition(N)` 
b) to learn models on each partition we use `mapPartitionsWithIndex`

The problem is that multiple partitions map to the same physical machine -- which launches multiple model builds on the same physical node (invoked by `mapPartitionsWithIndex`) -- causing the node to run out of memory (we have maxed the executor memory).

Is there a better way to design this ?

Comment: are you learning the same model on different partitions, or different models on different partitions?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the randomSplit() function which randomly splits a DataFrame into a set of DataFrames according to the provided weights.

Example (Pyspark):

given a df Dataframe

```
df = sc.parallelize([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]]).toDF(["a", "b"])
```

apply:

```
splittedDF = df.randomSplit([0.5, 0.5], 1234)
```